# pyautogui.locateAll() returns hundrets of similar positions when theres only 1 image onscreen

Tags: python, image-recognition, pyautogui

So i wanted to make a script that can tell me the positions of all markers onscreen.

```py
locate_markers = pyautogui.screenshot('C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/bot/locate_markers.png')
for pos in pyautogui.locateAll("C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/bot/MarkerTransparent2.PNG", "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/bot/locate_markers.PNG", confidence=0.6):
    print(pos)
```

[marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66uw.png) and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0AQu.jpg)

But when I run it, even when there is only one marker onscreen it outputs something like this:

```py
Box(left=534, top=428, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=535, top=428, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=536, top=428, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=537, top=428, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=538, top=428, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=539, top=428, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=540, top=428, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=541, top=428, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=535, top=429, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=536, top=429, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=537, top=429, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=538, top=429, width=59, height=68)
Box(left=539, top=429, width=59, height=68)
```

but doesn't stop until I end the program. Can someone tell me why it is behaving so weird and how I can fix it?

I found a similar post that said I should change the confidence value but that didn't work, it
either found a million or none at all.

btw. this is my first post(i just followed the guide that popped up), so if you have improvements on how to ask questions, let me know.

Comment: You should post images of the screenshot and the template you are looking for.

Comment: What's the length of locateAll()?